# How to programmatically disconnect a ssh user?

Tags: shell, ssh, kill

I need to force a disconnect all sessions for a given user. Since this user might be root as well I think it would be better to avoid killing the parent sshd process along the way.

Is there a portable way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't elegant but it would get the job done.

```
ps ax | grep 'sshd: <insert username here>' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill
```

Comment: What if 'username' is root ?

Comment: It worked for me.  The ssh process is still running and my root ssh session got disconnected

Comment: also one of the systems I use shows: "username 91642  0.0  0.8  66124  4292 ?        S    19:50   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -R" for "ps aux"

Comment: don't do `ps aux` just do `ps ax`.  That'll strip out a lot of the unnecessary columns.

Comment: which gives "91642 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -R" so no "sshd: " to separate sshd childs form parents

Comment: Are there any active ssh sessions on that host?

Comment: yes, including me. The parent sshd process is "6393 ?        Ss     0:04 /usr/sbin/sshd"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33337/discussion-between-david-king-and-ascobol).

Comment: The `grep|grep -v|awk` pipeline can be replaced with `grep -oP '^\s*\K\d+(?=.*[s]shd: username)'` (assumes GNU grep)

Comment: @glennjackman Sure but good luck deciphering that two years from now.  I prefer the original Unix philosophy of many simple steps piped together.

Comment: @Jakuje Not on my server.  The parent process didn't have a username associated with it so it wasn't killed.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly as to [David King's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250971/116858), but using `pkill` instead:

```
pkill -f "sshd: username"
```

or possibly

```
pkill -u username -f "sshd: username"
```